# Cylindrical incompressible Navier-Stokes, are the derivatives commuative?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, differentiation, navier-stokes

I am currently trying to understand a paper by Eckhardt et al. (https://doi.org/10.1017/S0022112007005629). In it, a transformation is performed on the cylindrical incompressible Navier-Stokes equation. As annotated in equation 3.1, $u_z$ and $v$ must be switched to exchange the derivative $\partial_z u_z$ in the continuity equation. However, in my view, $u_z \partial_z v = \partial_z u_zv - v \partial_z u_z$. I cannot determine where $\partial_z u_zv$ $\partial_z u_zv$ is left.

Right before it is shown that the integrals are commutative. Does this enable the switch?

[image]

Comment: The article you linked is behind a paywall for most people likely, this won't help many who might be able to help you.

Comment: The relevant equations are in the Screenshot.  I cannot share the cpmplete article due to copyright claims

Comment: The thing is more relevant information might exist in what is a scientific article, we link full articles here all the time. Anyways, since the object you are asking about is an integration over the entire region, perhaps it is that the integration by parts produces a total derivative term that *vanishes*.